# Preserve space in React rendered element

Tags: reactjs

From my backend service a string containing spaces is returned. When I `console.log` this value in my `render` method it shows the raw string with spaces.

The rendered element, however, is missing the values.

Example:

```
const a = "I am a text string"
```

is different from:

```
const a = "I  am a text string"
```

(Notice the extra space between "I" and "am".

The render method seems to be removing the extra space from my rendered output.

This is just an example, but the raw data that I try to show the end user *has* to contain the extra space. How can I force React to render the raw string, instead of doing some kind of text-formatting on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure if React JS messes up the space as it's just HTML. Use the following CSS on the element:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

**Working Demo:** [wmnk7rmq8 - CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wmnk7rmq8)

Comment: That was it. Thank you. It had nothing to do with React... I will set the answer as accepted when I can in 10 min.

Comment: @ThomasDarvik Working preview, if you need. [wmnk7rmq8 - CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wmnk7rmq8) Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with using `white-space: pre-wrap`, like the fact that you can't use that AND `text-overflow: ellipsis` (which requires `white-space: nowrap` to be useful).  The "safest" way I found is using Unicode spaces, which are NOT compressed by HTML by default...

`{a.replace(/ /g, "\u00a0")}`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions.

Adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your CSS:

```js
const a = "I    am a text    string"
const Text = props => <p className='txt'>{a}</p>

ReactDOM.render(<Text />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.txt {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Using the `pre` tag:

```js
const a = "I    am a text    string"
const Text = props => <pre>{a}</pre>

ReactDOM.render(<Text />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```